# Cannot connect to database via JDBC in Pehtaho Report Designer

Tags: mysql, jdbc, pentaho, connectivity, handshake

So, while trying to connect to Pentaho in Pentaho Report Designer, I am getting an error which says:

> Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on the host *host_name*?

```
using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

[image: This is the error that I get after trying to connect to a MySQL database hosted on a server. The credentials are absolutely fine.]

I have now included the jar file mentioned in the first answer and the connection says **OK**. But, when I preview or use a query using that connection, again I get the same error.

[image: After correction of the Jar issue!]

I am absolutely new to Pentaho. I got a few errors before which I could resolve. But, I have been stuck on this one for 2 days now. Cannot find anything regarding this.

Comment: Try connecting to the database using the same credentials using SquirrelSQL or another tool that uses JDBC drivers, and then run the same query. Does that work?

Comment: @lukfi - I already checked that. It is working.

Comment: This may prove to be useful - I don't know yet. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1324889

Answer (score 1):

May be Mysql connector is not there i think.

=> Before creating jdbc connection. Go to  these location Eg:- C:\report-designer-3.9.1\lib  and then check mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar file is their or not. If it's not their goto these (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) location and download jar file and copy that file and paste it in C:\report-designer-3.9.1\lib location.

=> Restart Pehtaho Report Designer again and check it now.

=> May be you have lower version of mysql jar file remove old mysql jar file and paste higher version of mysql jar.

I think your problem will be solved.

Thank you..

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The connection worked but the query throws the same error.

Comment: What version of Pentaho Report designer are you using?